# the description of Cauchy principle of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

**Question**：Is description
$$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\exists N\in\mathbb{Z^+},\text{s.t.}\forall n\gt N,\left| a_n-a_N\right|\lt\varepsilon$$
equivalent to convergence of the suquence $\{a_n\}$?

**Attempt**:
$(\Leftarrow)$Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.
Then for $\varepsilon/2\gt0$, $\exists N_0\in\mathbb{Z^+},\text{s.t.}\forall n\ge N_0,\left| a_n-A\right|\lt\varepsilon/2$.
Select $N=N_0$, then we have
$$\forall n\gt N,\left|a_n-a_N\right|\lt\left|a_n-A\right|+\left|a_N-A\right|\lt\varepsilon$$

**Obstacles**:
I have no way to prove the sufficiency or to give any counterexamples to falsify.

Comment: Are you asking whether a sequence being Cauchy is equivalent to convergence, or trying to prove it?

Comment: A Cauchy sequence of real numbers being convergent is a non trivial theorem, and it's not normal by any means to give it as a homework problem. Are you sure this is what you need to prove? When I first saw the question, I thought maybe you need to prove that your description is equivalent to the more standard definition of a Cauchy sequence. (where you require $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $m,n>N$) Maybe this is what you actually have to show?

Comment: @Mark Your understanding is right.

Answer (score 3):

If your sequence fulfills what you wrote, then for any $\;\epsilon>0\;\exists N\in\Bbb N\; $ s.t. if $\;n, m\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;n,m>N\;$ we get:

$$|a_n-a_m|=|a_n-a_N+a_N-a_m|\le|a_n-a_N|+|a_m-a_N|<2\epsilon$$

and thus your sequence is Cauchy and then in any complete metric space, e.g. in the reals $\;\Bbb R\;$ or in the complex $\;\Bbb C\;$ , the sequence converges.

Comment: There is a small typo, $A_N$ should be $a_n$ I think.

Comment: @MarvinsSister You're right, thank you. Edited.

Comment: Appreciate! But I have an additional question. Actually I think my description is simpler than the standard one. Is there any advantages of the standard description which requires |am−an|<ϵ for all m,n>N?